# preventing dupplicate serial number for registration in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, concurrency, locking

i've created a web-application in which i've to submit a form for which there will be a serial number generated , on submission serial number should be given to only for one registration, say if two application submit at the very same instance there will be chance of getting duplicate serial number for the two registration.

i've wrote a code which is as given below, can we prevent the above mentioned problem using this code, please give valuable suggestion on this.

```
public String registration(){

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction t = null;
    try {
    t = session.beginTransaction();

    TableSerialGenerator serialnoObj;
    serialnoObj=generateSerialNo("1", session);
    String Serial_No=serialnoObj.getPrefix()+"-"+serialnoObj.getCurrentIndex();

    Registration res=new Registration(Serial_No,......);
    session.save(res);

    t.commit();
    return SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if(t!= null)
             t.rollback();
    return ERROR;
    }
    finally {
    session.close();
    }
}


public TableSerialGenerator generateSerialNo(String type,Session session)
{
String serialno="";
TableSerialGenerator obj=new TableSerialGenerator();
try
{

    obj=(TableSerialGenerator) session.get(TableSerialGenerator.class, Integer.parseInt(type), LockMode.UPGRADE);

    if(obj.getCurrentIndex() == null)
    {
      obj.setCurrentIndex(obj.getStartIndex());
    }
    else
    {
      obj.setCurrentIndex(obj.getCurrentIndex()+1);
    }
    session.save(obj);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in generateSerialNo method of CommonHibernateClass class....."+e);
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return obj;
}
```

**TableSerialGenerator.java**

```
public class TableSerialGenerator  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;

     private String prefix;
     private String suffix;
     private Integer startIndex;
     private String type;
     private Integer currentIndex;
     private String status;
     private Date createdDate;
     private Date modifiedDate;

//getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid possible multithreading problems you could use syncronized keyword in the method in which you obtain the serial number "generateSerialNo" , this avoid to obtain the same serial number twice. 
But there is strategy in JPA that you can use to obtain new serial value, if you want to use a table consider using @TableGenerator.

```
@TableGenerator(
            name="empGen", 
            table="ID_GEN", 
            pkColumnName="GEN_KEY", 
            valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", 
            pkColumnValue="EMP_ID", 
            allocationSize=1)
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=TABLE, generator="empGen")
        int id;
```

This will create a new serial number in each save operation for an specific entity.

[TableGenerator API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html)